# VB.NET Dataview Rowfilter by Time

Tags: vb.net, time, dataview, rowfilter

I'd like to extend my `dataview` filtering. Some tables contain `datetime` columns.

Searching for a specified date is implemented already, but how might it be possible to search for a time pattern like 10:20?

My current statement is the following, which seems plausible, but doesn't work:

`"columnname >= '10:20:00' AND columnname <= '10:20:59'"`

Is there something like a `time()` function, e.g."
`time(columnname) >= '10:20...`

Maybe another way to escape the irrelevant date part e.g.: `>= '% 10:20...` ?

Could not find anything related to this question? Am I realy the first who want such a functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq (Imports System.Linq) for this by adding System.Data.DataSetExtensions-reference to your project and doing:

```
Dim rows As DataRow() = (From row In myDatatable.AsEnumerable
                                Where row.Field(Of DateTime)("column").Hour > 10).ToArray()
```

Or better yet:

```
Dim time As New TimeSpan(10, 20, 59)

Dim rows As DataRow() = (From row In myDatatable.AsEnumerable
                             Where row.Field(Of DateTime)("column").TimeOfDay > time).ToArray()
```

Comment: thank you for your response. indeed that was a solution. I could select the row-ID in the linq query and set the rowfilter to something like "row-ID IN(, where I put the aggregated ID's... As I said, that was a solution, but maybe a bit too much overhead??? =/

Comment: What do you mean overhead? I would recommend Linq for all your queries against the datatable, it's strongly typed and made for this purpose. DataTable.Select on the other hand is not strongly typed and in a situation like this, it's much harder to use. As a side note, reading data to datatables in the first place is a bit outdated, entityframework would be a better alternative.

Comment: with overhead I mean it's more memorylasting than required. First I'd need to execute the linq query, parsing, casting the field for every row that amount of times I need to check in the where part... in this example twice: Where row.Field(Of DateTime)("column").TimeOfDay >= time(h:m):00 AND ...TimeOfDay <= time(h:m):59.... afterwards I put the IDs in the rowfilter property, letting the dataview process that statement. Depending on the table I might have more than just one datetime column. Searching not with every keystroke, but after some delay... In my case for ~12.000 rows

Comment: Most efficient way of doing  this is SQL, so do it there if you can. About the overhead, doing this with .select-method has no less overhead than doing it with linq. Also there will be no casting to datetime if the column is already of type datetime. That (Of DateTime) only tells the compiler that the column is of datetime type.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with th following solution:

RowFilter = Convert(columnname, 'System.String') like '% " & pTime.ToString("hh:mm") & "%'

This is everything what I need for the moment. For searching >=/<=/ I might come back to Eskos proposal.

Thanks